# MySQL - Need to select MIN and MAX with a WHERE clause, as part of a larger query

Tags: mysql, database

I have something like this:

```
SELECT foo1, foo2, foo3, MAX(foo4) AS max FROM table WHERE foo5 = bar;
```

The thing is, in addition to having the WHERE foo5 = bar clause apply to the whole query, I also want to specify a condition for foo4. I don't just want the maximum value of foo4 from the whole table, but the maximum value of foo4 when another field is equal to something specific. So something like this.

```
SELECT foo1, foo2, foo3, MAX(foo4 WHERE field=otherthing) AS max FROM table WHERE foo5 = bar;
```

How can I do this?

EDIT: Here is some more detail. This is my current query:

```
SELECT Car_Type, Car_Imm, MIN(Use_Kilom) AS Init_Kilom, 
       MAX(Use_Kilom) AS Final_Kilom, MAX(Use_Kilom) 
       - MIN(Use_Kilom) AS Distance_Kilom, null, null, 
       SUM(Use_Amount) AS Amount_Total, 
       SUM(Use_Liter) / 20 AS Liter_Total, null, null 
FROM fueluse, car 
WHERE Use_Car = Car_Code AND 
       (Use_Date BETWEEN '$datefrom' AND '$dateto')
```

In this case, MAX(Use_Kilom) and MIN(Use_Kilom) are both getting the absolute maximum and minimum values from the entire table. I just want them to get the maximum value for each Use_Car value.

I tried replacing them with the following, respectively:

```
(SELECT MIN(Use_Kilom) FROM fueluse, car WHERE Use_Car = Car_Code) AS Init_Kilom
(SELECT MAX(Use_Kilom) FROM fueluse, car WHERE Use_Car = Car_Code) AS Final_Kilom
```

But they're still giving me the absolute minimum and maximum values in the entire fueluse table's Use_Kilom field rather than just for each Use_Car's maximum and minimum values of Use_Kilom. Note that Use_Car and Car_Code are linked as a foreign key.

Comment: It would help if you could publish sample data and expected result.

Comment: I edited my question with some more detail.

Comment: why are you deliberately selecting `null`s ?

Comment: The nulls are just a placeholder for something else at this point. I'm just trying to figure out how I can get the MIN and MAX to get the respective values for each Use_Car value and not the absolute greatest/smallest. The same applies for the SUM parts, I'm just having trouble figuring out the syntax to get it to work properly.

Comment: You're missing `GROUP BY` the car. Side note - are you using old non-ansi style joins?

Comment: That was it! The GROUP BY fixed everything and also made it so that every individual car was properly being shown. I thought that was a separate issue and was going to tackle it after I solved this one. Thank you. Regarding joins, I'm not super experienced with SQL yet and haven't actually used joins before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect to see a group by clause then using aggregate functions(min,max,sum etc). In this case probably group by Car_Type, Car_Imm. The implict join should also be changed to an explicit join.

```
SELECT Car_Type, Car_Imm, MIN(Use_Kilom) AS Init_Kilom, 
       MAX(Use_Kilom) AS Final_Kilom, MAX(Use_Kilom) 
       - MIN(Use_Kilom) AS Distance_Kilom, null, null, 
       SUM(Use_Amount) AS Amount_Total, 
       SUM(Use_Liter) / 20 AS Liter_Total, null, null 
FROM fueluse
join  car on Use_Car = Car_Code AND 
where (Use_Date BETWEEN '$datefrom' AND '$dateto')
group by Car_Type, Car_Imm
```

It would make things clearer if you qualified your fieldnames with the table names they belong to (or their alias)

Comment: It was indeed simply missing group by. I only added GROUP BY Use_Car to my initial query as suggested by Bridge and everything works now.

Comment: @PSalmon I'm guessing that extra `AND` after the join clause is a typo?